# Aligning sequences with missing values

Tags: r, sequence, alignment, missing-data, cross-correlation

The language I'm using is R, but you don't necessarily need to know about R to answer the question.

**Question:**
I have a sequence that can be considered the ground truth, and another sequence that is a shifted version of the first, with some missing values. I'd like to know how to align the two.

**setup**

I have a sequence `ground.truth` that is basically a set of times:

```
ground.truth <- rep( seq(1,by=4,length.out=10), 5 ) +
                rep( seq(0,length.out=5,by=4*10+30), each=10 )
```

Think of `ground.truth` as times where I'm doing the following:

```
{take a sample every 4 seconds for 10 times, then wait 30 seconds} x 5
```

I have a second sequence `observations`, which is `ground.truth` *shifted* with 20% of the values missing:

```
nSamples <- length(ground.truth)
idx_to_keep <- sort(sample( 1:nSamples, .8*nSamples ))
theLag <- runif(1)*100
observations <- ground.truth[idx_to_keep] + theLag
nObs     <- length(observations)
```

If I plot these vectors this is what it looks like (remember, think of these as times):

[image]

**What I've tried. I want to**:

- calculate the shift (`theLag` in my example above)
- calculate a vector `idx` such that `ground.truth[idx] == observations - theLag`

First, assume we know `theLag`. Note that `ground.truth[1]` is not necessarily `observations[1]-theLag`. In fact, we have `ground.truth[1] == observations[1+lagI]-theLag` for some `lagI`.

To calculate this, I thought I'd use cross-correlation (`ccf` function).

However, whenever I do this I get a lag with a max. cross-correlation of 0, meaning `ground.truth[1] == observations[1] - theLag`. But I've tried this in examples where I've explicitly *made sure* that `observations[1] - theLag` is **not** `ground.truth[1]` (i.e. modify `idx_to_keep` to make sure it doesn't have 1 in it).

The shift `theLag` shouldn't affect the cross-correlation (isn't `ccf(x,y) == ccf(x,y-constant)`?) so I was going to work it out later.

Perhaps I'm misunderstanding though, because `observations` doesn't have as many values in it as `ground.truth`? Even in the simpler case where I set `theLag==0`, the cross correlation function still fails to identify the correct lag, which leads me to believe I'm thinking about this wrong.

**Does anyone have a general methodology for me to go about this, or know of some R functions/packages that could help?**

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Post the code that you're using for the correlation.  If you're correlating them value-by-value, it is certainly not going to give the results that you want.

Comment: As mentioned in the question, I'm using `ccf`: `ccf(ground.truth, observations)`. I think I'm not getting what I want since these are of different lengths due to the missing values.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For the lag, you can compute all the differences (distances) between your two sets of points:

```
diffs <- outer(observations, ground.truth, '-')
```

Your lag should be the value that appears `length(observations)` times:

```
which(table(diffs) == length(observations))
# 55.715382960625 
#              86
```

Double check:

```
theLag
# [1] 55.71538
```

The second part of your question is easy once you have found `theLag`:

```
idx <- which(ground.truth %in% (observations - theLag))
```

Comment: I absolutely love the sheer simplicity of this, but sadly I presented a slightly easier version of my actual question; because of limited precision in measuring the time stamps for both `ground.truth` and `observations`, `theLag` is not really constant over the entire series. It oscillates between n seconds and n+1 fairly unpredictably. I'm trying to modify your technique to see if I can still make it work though, because I just didn't think about it like that!

Comment: You, Sir/Madam, are a genius. I would never have thought to think about it like that and have been banging my head against the wall so hard I almost made a hole in it! Since I don't have an exactly-constant shift, I did `which.min(abs(table(diffs)-length(observations)))` for `theLag`, and hence instead of using `%in%` I used `idx <- vapply( recons, function(t) which.min(abs(ground.truth-t)), -1)`.

Answer (score 3):

The following should work if your time series are not too long.

You have two vectors of time-stamps, 
the second one being a shifted and incomplete copy of the first,
and you want to find by how much it was shifted.

```
# Sample data
n <- 10
x <- cumsum(rexp(n,.1))
theLag <- rnorm(1)
y <- theLag + x[sort(sample(1:n, floor(.8*n)))]
```

We can try all possible lags and, for each one, 
compute how bad the alignment is, 
by matching each observed timestamp with the closest
"truth" timestamp.

```
# Loss function
library(sqldf)
f <- function(u) {
  # Put all the values in a data.frame
  d1 <- data.frame(g="truth",    value=x)
  d2 <- data.frame(g="observed", value=y+u)
  d <- rbind(d1,d2)
  # For each observed value, find the next truth value
  # (we could take the nearest, on either side, 
  # but it would be more complicated)
  d <- sqldf("
    SELECT A.g, A.value, 
           ( SELECT MIN(B.value) 
             FROM   d AS B 
             WHERE  B.g='truth' 
             AND    B.value >= A.value
           ) AS next
    FROM   d AS A
    WHERE  A.g = 'observed'
  ")
  # If u is greater than the lag, there are missing values.
  # If u is smaller, the differences decrease 
  # as we approach the lag.
  if(any(is.na(d))) {
    return(Inf)
  } else {
    return( sum(d$`next` - d$value, na.rm=TRUE) )
  }
}
```

We can now search for the best lag.

```
# Look at the loss function
sapply( seq(-2,2,by=.1), f )

# Minimize the loss function.
# Change the interval if it does not converge, 
# i.e., if it seems in contradiction with the values above
# or if the minimum is Inf
(r <- optimize(f, c(-3,3)))
-r$minimum
theLag # Same value, most of the time
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the work that has obviously gone in to this, I hadn't thought about this in an optimisation sense either (my attempts were all in the vein of manipulating the periodicity of the times (every 4(ish) seconds 10 times with a 30(ish) second gap) to align the two sequences). You answer does work too (and with `theLag` I can calculate `idx`), but I'll accept @flodel's because of its pure simplicity. Thanks!